# Threads created on my service get killed when I close the activity

Tags: android, multithreading, io, android-activity, android-service

I created an activity that calls a service and the service creates a Thread that send and receive some data to/from the server, I can open other apps and the Service and the Thread run ok, but when I close the activity, the Service keeps running but the thread stops working. Why??? How can I keep the Thread running!!.

Code

Activity

```
package com.connectus.app;

public class ConnectUsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_us);

        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConnectUsService.class);
        startService(startServiceIntent);
}
```

Service

```
package com.connectus.app;

public class ConnectUsService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    private DataInputStream in;
                    private BufferedReader br;
                    private DataOutputStream out;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Socket server=null;
                        try{
                            server=new Socket("10.10.40.58",4444);
                            in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                            out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                            while(true){
                                out.writeUTF("aaaaa");
                                String leido=in.readUTF();

                                out.writeUTF("asdf");
                                                                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                            }
                        }catch(IOException ioe){
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

This is just a part of my code, I hope it helps.

Comment: You must have a bug. Please post your relevant code.

Comment: But I can not see any error on Logcat. Let me put the code.

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: I faced similar behaviour, however I was dealing with a background service scheduled to run at startup, on careful examination of the logCat I came to know how the OS was killing my process, I had also tried to setthread priority to highest. This would be a normal message of killing an app, just ctrl+c on your logCat window and paste it into a text editor, then check it.

Comment: done!, i added the code. any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know the thread stops running?

Comment: I put some logs on the Thread and additionally the server stops receiving data and show me an error, java.io.EOFException at ava.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source) at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)

Comment: How do you know your service is still running? I'll bet Android is killing your process. Your Service probably isn't running and neither is your Thread.

Comment: When I go to the application manager, I can see the application and show 0 proccesses and 1 service. Additionally, I can select the app on the application manager and stop the service manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, finally i find a solution. It was necesary to use the setForeground() method, I just added this code to my service Class:

```
Notification note=new Notification();
startForeground(1337, note);
```

According to my research, this code is used to prevent that the service get killed by itself.

best regards!

Comment: The service never kills itself, it can technically stop doing what it was doing and Android then stops it. A Foreground service doesn't prevent the service to be killed, it just greatly decreases the chances of this happening. Code on the safe side, assume the worst.